String Manipulation based on Char Length in a dataframe
I wanted to do some string manipulation based on Char length condition.
I have this table, let's called it sample table.



RiskCode




A01


A02.999



I want to transform the RiskCode column in sample table by creating new column such as this:



RiskCode
RiskCode2




A01
A01.00


A02.999
A02.99



I have created a function to transform the string:
icd_transform <- function(x){
  if(nchar(x) > 6) {
    return(substr(x,1,6))
  } else if (nchar(x) == 5) {
    return(paste(x,"0",sep=""))
  } else if (nchar(x) == 3) {
    return(paste(x,".00",sep=""))
  } else {return(x)}
}

I tried to use function above on apply to see the results first.
apply(sample$RiskCode,2,icd_transform)

But, I found an error below:
Error in apply(sample$RiskCode, 2, icd_transform) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

Could you guys help me to solve the problem? Thank you.

@Edward Sorry, I update the question, have solved on "condition has length > 1" error

sapply(x, icd_transform). Apply is not used on vectors but matrices (can also be used on df).

FYI no need for return().

Furthermore, is the expected format always “‹LETTER›‹two digits›.‹three digits›”? Because if so, then the logic can be expressed as a single expression without conditional branches via sprintf().

This has already been addressed in the comments but I thought I would expand on those comments.
apply(X, 2, ...) needs X to be matrix or other object with at least 2 dimensions (in which case it calls the function once per column) but in the question's code X is a plain vector (which has no dimensions at all).
dim(sample$RiskCode)
## NULL

1) We can instead use sapply which iterates over the components of a vector (or list).  That will work with icd_transform as given in the question.
sapply(sample$RiskCode, icd_transform)

The Vectorize function mentioned in the another answer would also work.
2) or we could rewrite icd_transform to accept vectors by using ifelse rather than if...else...  in which case we don't even need sapply.  This creates a new data frame, sample2, with the result.  Here x can be a vector.  Note that strtrim(x, 6) will return x unchanged if x has less than or equal to 6 characters and otherwise truncate it to 6 characters.
icd_transform2 <- function(x) {
  suffix <- ifelse(nchar(x) == 5, "0",
    ifelse(nchar(x) == 3, ".00", ""))
  x |>
    strtrim(6) |>
    paste0(suffix)
}

sample2 <- sample |> transform(RiskCode2 = icd_transform2(RiskCode))

3) The dplyr package has a useful case_match which provides a multi-way switch that is vectorized.
library(dplyr)

icd_transform3 <- function(x) {
  case_match(nchar(x), 
    3 ~ paste0(x, ".00"),
    5 ~ paste0(x, "0"),
    .default = strtrim(x, 6))
}

sample2 <- sample |> mutate(RiskCode2 = icd_transform3(RiskCode))

4) One comment referred to using sprintf and depending on what the general case is you may be able to use something like this:
library(dplyr)

icd_transform4 <- function(x) {
  sprintf("%s%05.2f", strtrim(x, 1), as.numeric(substring(strtrim(x, 6), 2)))
}

sample |>
  mutate(RiskCode2 = icd_transform4(RiskCode))

Although not necessarily of use for the question here you may be interested in the icd package on github.  If on Windows install Rtools first.  (Rtools contains a C compiler and other tools that are needed to build icd.)
library(devtools)
install_github("jackwasey/icd")

Note
Input in reproducible form:
sample <- data.frame(RiskCode = c("A01", "A02.999"))


An approach using Vectorize
sample$RiskCode2 <- Vectorize(\(x) icd_transform(x))(sample$RiskCode)

sample
  RiskCode RiskCode2
1      A01    A01.00
2  A02.999    A02.99


Vectorize(\(x) icd_transform(x)) => Vectorize(icd_transform).

The more verbose version imo helps understand the function-nature of Vectorize and shows the connection between the anonymous function and the argument.

You can directly change your variable without creating a function:
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

sample <- data.frame(RiskCode = c("A01", "A02.999"))
sample <- mutate(sample,
                 RiskCode2 = case_when(
                   nchar(RiskCode) > 6 ~ substr(RiskCode, 1, 6),
                   nchar(RiskCode) == 5 ~ paste0(RiskCode, "0"),
                   nchar(RiskCode) == 3 ~ paste0(RiskCode, ".00")
                 ))
print(sample)
#>   RiskCode RiskCode2
#> 1      A01    A01.00
#> 2  A02.999    A02.99

Created on 2024-07-19 with reprex v2.1.0

Another tidyverse take:
# Pkgs (dplyr, stringr) ---------------------------------------------------
library(tidyverse)

# Sample data -------------------------------------------------------------
my_df <- structure(
  list(risk_code = c("A01", "A02.999")), 
  class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -2L))

# Code (just paste0 and str_sub) ------------------------------------------
my_df <- mutate(
  my_df, 
  
  new_risk_code = str_sub(
    paste0(
      risk_code,                                        # "A00.00" is the
      str_sub("A00.00", str_length(risk_code) + 1, 6)), # default pattern
    1, 6))                                              # with length 6

# Output ------------------------------------------------------------------
print(my_df)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   risk_code new_risk_code
#>   <chr>     <chr>        
#> 1 A01       A01.00       
#> 2 A02.999   A02.99

Created on 2024-07-19 with reprex v2.1.0

In base R, you could use regex + sprintf. Everything is vectorized:
a <- strcapture("(\\D+)(\\d{2}).?(\\d{2})?", df$risk_code, list("", 0,0)) 
do.call(sprintf, c("%s%02d.%02d", replace(a, is.na(a), 0)))
[1] "A01.00" "A02.99"


Another option is the gsubfn package
fn <- function(x, y, z){
  y <- ifelse(nzchar(y), as.numeric(y), 0)
  z <- ifelse(nzchar(z), as.numeric(z), 0)
  sprintf("%s%02d.%02d", x, y, z)
}

gsubfn::gsubfn("(\\D+)(\\d{2}).?(\\d{2})?.*",fn, df$risk_code)
[1] "A01.00" "A02.99"

